# MapReduce retain input order from mapper to reducer java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a weather dataset. I process it and find the average temperature value on a certain day, but when I try to go beyond the month, the data comes into the reducer in a different order, and I need to save the order for further temperature calculations for the week, month ... What am I doing wrong ? How can I keep order?
Dataset example:
(MM/DD/YY) temp
3/1/11     5
3/1/11     4
3/8/11     7
3/8/11     6
4/1/11     9
5/1/11    12
In reducer I recieve keys in this order:
3/1/11
4/1/11
5/1/11
3/8/11
My Map:

```
     protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    try {
        //MM/DD/YYYY
        String userDateBefore = "03/01/11";
        String userDateAfter = "05/01/11";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
        format.applyPattern("MM/dd/yy");
        Date userDateBeforeFormatted = null;
        try {
            userDateBeforeFormatted = format.parse(userDateBefore);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Date userDateAfterFormatted = null;
        try {
            userDateAfterFormatted = format.parse(userDateAfter);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] strArr = value.toString().split(",");
        String date = strArr[2];
        Date incomeDate = null;
        try {
            incomeDate = format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;

        Text dateText;
        float airTemp;
        if(incomeDate.before(userDateAfterFormatted) || incomeDate.equals(userDateAfterFormatted)
                && incomeDate.after(userDateBeforeFormatted) || incomeDate.equals(userDateBeforeFormatted)) {
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
            dateText = new Text(dateFormat.format(incomeDate));
            airTemp = Float.parseFloat(strArr[14]);
            context.write(dateText, new FloatWritable(airTemp));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My Reducer:

```
protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<FloatWritable> floatTypes, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    counter = 0;
    sum = 0;
    for (FloatWritable f : floatTypes) {
        sum += f.get();
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println(key);
    hm.put(key.toString(), sum/counter);
    context.write(new Text("Day: " + key.toString() + " avg temp: " + sum/(counter)), nullWritable);
}
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of your date formats - the standard would be YYYY-MM-DD. This will ensure correct sorting.

Comment: As stated, fix the formatting, otherwise you need to force data into one reducer to sort anything, which defeats the purpose of mapreduce. Also, no one generally writes mapreduce code anymore. Is this a requirement for some assignment?